# init process dies on linux kernel start

Tags: linux-kernel, powerpc, initrd

I am trying to bringup kernel on a custom p2020 board. The kernel crashes with below exception.

> init[1]: unhandled signal 4 at 4801b9dc nip 4801b9dc lr 48002b08 code 3000

It is dying in the same way for both `initrd` as well as `ramfs`.

I am using a initrd used to be working on t104x based board.
What can be the cause of above error? Is it that initrd is not fit for P2020?
Do we need to recompile initrd for specific processor?

Comment: Which distribution you run on it?

Comment: How is distribution important? It is all custom in my case.                                        BTW, I created a initramfs using busybox and tried to test it. I no longer get "signal-4 (illegal instruction)", but getting segmentation fault (signal-11).

Comment: Recently I had similar issue with my Buildroot environment, so, I did fix it. It's really depends on what the code you are using. Btw, have you check what signal 4 means in case of failed init process?

Comment: I understand. I progressed further with the help of ramfs creation. (referred [http://landley.net/writing/rootfs-howto.html] , section Using an initramfs_list configuration file).  With this minimal ramfs, I think kernel tries to run init process (init is just a hello world program). But its is not printing anything and just hangs.  On a closer look the sys_open(/dev/console) returns -19 i.e. ENODEV.  It is strange since I think the cpio archive has a node named dev/console with 777 permissions.  Because of this failure, I get a   Warning: unable to open an initial console  Any idea?

Comment: Hi,   I progressed further with creation /dev/console node in initramfs [refer]:(landley.net/writing/rootfs-howto.html).   Now I no longer get ENODEV.  It seems still there is a console problem, i still do not get any console output.  Now I am in dark.   1. If init exist (no loop), the kernel crashed, but it also means kernel is executing init program, so might not be an issue of glibc etc.   2. No output on console, what can be the cause of this. I do not create any other node that /dev/console in initramfs. How does it get redirected to ttyS0?   I am in total darkness now...

Comment: @AndyShevchenko What fix you did with your buildroot environment? I am building for ppc and 3.10.65